# Setting a variable to null value in inline if statement

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use the following code to check for a `DBNull` and set the variable to nothing if it is, or a short if it isn't. The problem is it is failing to set the variable to `Nothing` and sets it to a `0` instead. Anybody know why?

```
variable = If(currentRow.Item("variable") Is DBNull.Value,
    Nothing, CShort(currentRow.Item("variable")))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `variable` is declared `As Short?` then the code works with a slight tweak: you need to cast either operand of `If` to the target type first:

```
variable = If(condition, CType(Nothing, Short?), CShort(…))
```

(You could also have cast the third operand instead, or both.)

This cast is necessary because of how `If` deduces types: if the two result types mismatch, a common type is deduced which is the *closest parent type*, i.e. a type from which both inherit. However, with `Nothing`, new rules come into play because as far as VB is concerned, `Nothing` is already a valid `Short` – a default-initialised one (see old answer below for explanation). So VB doesn’t try any type coercion, it simply uses `Short` as the return value.

---

Old answer below, assuming that OP had declared `variable As Short`:

You cannot set value types to `Nothing`. If you assign `Nothing` to a value type then it will be set to its type’s default value instead – which is `0` for `Short`.

You can test this easily:

```
Dim s as Short = Nothing
Console.WriteLine(s)
```

Setting a value type to `Nothing` is the same as invoking its default constructor (`New Short()`) or declaring a new variable of that type without initialising it. The corresponding operation in C# would be to assign `default(T)` (`short s = default(short)`).

If you want to represent `null` value types, you have to use [*nullable* types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx):

```
Dim s as Short? = Nothing
```

Now `s` is of type `Nullable<Short>` (`Short?` is a shortcut of that) and can be assigned a proper `Nothing`.

Comment: Right, but my variable is already declared above (should've mentioned that) as "Short?". So, shouldn't this work?

Comment: @user1335008 Ah. That changes everything. Wait, let me edit the answer.